# How do we resize the images in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am beginner in Ios in my project i am displaying the image on table-list and so for everything is ok

but images actually coming from services some are too small some are coming big

how can i scale the images and how can fit them

### my code:-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 45, 45)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[Mainarray1  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    Cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [Cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

    return Cell;
}
```

Comment: isn't `Cell.imageView.contentMode` should be `imageView.contentMode`

Answer (score 0):

use below for getting the original size of the image and

```
imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

use below for stretching and fitting the image for whatever size required :

```
imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Answer (score 0):

Resize your image .

```
- (UIImage *) generatePhotoThumbnail:(UIImage *)image1 withSide:(CGFloat)ratio
{
// Create a thumbnail version of the image for the event object.

CGSize size = image1.size;
CGSize croppedSize;

CGFloat offsetX = 0.0;
CGFloat offsetY = 0.0;

// check the size of the image, we want to make it
// a square with sides the size of the smallest dimension.
// So clip the extra portion from x or y coordinate

if (size.width > size.height) {
    offsetX = (size.height - size.width) / 2;
    croppedSize = CGSizeMake(size.height, size.height);
} else {
    offsetY = (size.width - size.height) / 2;
    croppedSize = CGSizeMake(size.width, size.width);
}

// Crop the image before resize
CGRect clippedRect = CGRectMake(offsetX * -1, offsetY * -1, croppedSize.width, croppedSize.height);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image1 CGImage], clippedRect);
// Done cropping

// Resize the image
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ratio, ratio);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
[[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef] drawInRect:rect];
UIImage *thumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Done Resizing

return thumbnail;
}
```

Set your image

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 45, 45)];
imageView.image = [self generatePhotoThumbnail:[UIImage imageNamed:[Mainarray1  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] withSide:150.0];//;
Cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[Cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

return Cell;
}
```

Hope it will help you .